# How to use Extensions of Cytoscape

Tags: javascript, java, cytoscape.js, cytoscape, cytoscape-web

Div around each node that shows up on tapping a node
[image]

I am trying to achieve as in this video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IMN8j-AvZAE (The attached screenshot is from the video itself)

My question to the Cytoscape team is :

- Assuming that in order to achieve the functionality as in the above-mentioned video and the attachment I will have to use popper extension of cytoscape and in order to do so do I have to download the popper.js and cytoscape-popper.js from GitHub and include them in my index.html via script tag and then initialize it using Cytoscape function of my index.js file? please advise and share a sample code for the same.

Comment: It is unclear what you're asking.  Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This question was reviewed by the Cytosacpe and cytoscape.js teams, but we couldn't quite understand what you're trying to do or how to help. Can you provide more context and details.

Comment: Thanks for replying, Please find above the edited question.